# Attempting to install nvm on aws ubuntu instance

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, nvm

I am using this command.

nvm - curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.1/install.sh | bash

This is the error I get:
No command 'nvm' found, did you mean:
 Command 'pvm' from package 'pvm' (universe)
 etc.

My .bashrc looks like this at the bottom:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
source ~/nvm/nvm.sh
```

And my .profile looks like this:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
[[ -s $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

node -v

v6.10.2

What is the problem here?
All help is appreciated.  I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: Just run curl...  Without nvm

Comment: wow.  smh...thanks

Answer (score 1):

The command you want to run is:

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.1/install.sh | bash`

you cannot run nvm if you haven't install it and is not in the ubuntu repositories.

You need to have curl installed so might need to install it:

`sudo apt-get install curl`

Curl downloads the [install.sh](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/v0.33.1/install.sh) script and pipe it to bash to run it.

Remember to source your .bashrc afte running the script:

`source ~/.bashrc`